# Show that for any sets A and B that A Δ B = A^c Δ B^c.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So what I have so far is:

---

{x|xϵA ^ x∉b|}

A∩B^c

I can't figure out how to get to A^c Δ B^c.
I'm also not sure if I'm going down the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x \in A$ if and only if $x \not \in A^c$, and likewise for $B$. You can use these facts to translate the definition of $A \triangle B$ in terms of $A^c$ and $B^c$ to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You have that: $(A\triangle B) = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B)$

Now, what is $(A^\complement\triangle B^\complement)$ equal to?

Comment: A∁△B∁=(A∩B∁)∪(A∁∩B)?